# can't solve Problem with react-native-svg

Tags: react-native

I get a few problems when doing react-native run-android 
* What went wrong
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve project :react-native-svg.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-svg: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

Comment: rn version ? did you link it ?

Comment: Have you linked react-native-svg with android?

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.54.2

Comment: i've done react-native link react-native-svg, what should i do?

Comment: what is the "react-native-svg" version are you using?